# Why ternary operator gives an Error without brackets?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator, ternary

I have four lines of code like this:

```
let postId = // <== maybe undefined or string;
const sections = // <== maybe null or an array of sections with posts objects.

postId = postId || (sections ? sections[0]?.posts[0]?.id : null);
console.log(postId || sections ? sections[0]?.posts[0]?.id : null);
```

The third line is working and I understand why - If `postId` is falsy, then compute right part of an expression in brackets where I use ternary with optional array item and optional object parameters.

But the fourth line gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
```

I do not understand why brackets is important in this case.

Comment: Operator precedence. Your fourth line is equivalent to `console.log((postId || sections) ? sections[0]?.posts[0]?.id : null);` (note `postId || sections` is grouped). *(edit: not my downvote)*

Comment: Operator precedence. || is higher than ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - thank you man. Now clear about this. Simple and short.

Answer (score 0):

*fourth line gives me an error*

The reason behind that is your ternary operator is now working on `postId || sections`. Hence, Surround your right side statement in parenthesis in order to prevent it to consider left side variable as a part of ternary operation.

It should be **:**

```
console.log(postId || (sections ? sections[0]?.posts[0]?.id : null));
```